# Trying to apply a style on a GridView row about to be deleted

Tags: css, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to style a GridView which displays as a table.  Specifically, when the user clicks delete for a row, there's a MessageBox that appears for them to confirm it. I'd like to apply a style to the row then. Unfortunately, with my code as-is, the style only applies to the row after they've cancelled the deletion.

I had no issues applying a style when the user wants to edit a row.

```
// Works as intended.
protected void gv_Items_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e) {
    my_GridView.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].CssClass = "selected_row";
    // Rest of the editing logic
}

//Style is erroneously only applied AFTER the MessageBox
protected void gv_Items_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    my_GridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].CssClass = "deleting_row";
    System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult dr = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(
                    "Are you sure you want to DELETE this item?",
                    "Confirm",
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
    if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No)
        return;   // Cancel the deletion
// Rest of the deletion logic
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the effect I described? Thank you

Comment: This was disappointing. I did my best to provide enough information, and show what I've tried while keeping the problem minimal. I have nothing to show for my effort here.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the dialog is blocking the thread for changing the css class?

Could you try running the dialog.show async?

Comment: This is not a very descriptive answer. Also, when writing a solution, you don't ask the person to log something. That is written in the comments.